# Error while executing maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jpa

I create a maven project

> HTTP ERROR: 503 Problem accessing /. Reason: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
>   Powered by Jetty://

I got the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core]
>   Offending resource: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/app-jpa-config.xml]
>
> ```
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
> ```

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Annotation scan -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.entities.*" />
    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>

        <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/smart" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="20" />
        <property name="allowCreate" value="true" />
        <property name="alwaysUseNewSession" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.myapp.entities</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Have you got the Jetty server running?

Comment: I run the following commands : mvn install ,cd webapp,mvn jetty:run-war

Comment: The problem seems to be in locating http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd - can your server reach that URL?

Comment: @AshleyFrieze , yes I can open the page .

Comment: Do you have the ActiveMQ jars in your project?